# RoR/HAML/HTML add a new row after third element in html using ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

My index page looks like:

```
.subfeatures.row
  - @collection_pages.each do |collection_page|
    %div{class: "subfeature-0#{collection_page.position} columns four"}
      = link_to collection_page do
        .img
          = image_tag collection_page.cover_image
          .content
            %h3.title
              = collection_page.link
            %hr
            %p.description View Collection >
```

Given that I have 5 items.
This is generating:

```
    <div class="sub features row">
      <div class="subfeature-01 columns four">
      <div class="subfeature-02 columns four">
      <div class="subfeature-03 columns four">
      <div class="subfeature-04 columns four">
      <div class="subfeature-05 columns four">
   </div>
```

I need it to generate the following somehow, pretty much each row can contain 3 items:

```
  <div class="sub features row">
    <div class="subfeature-01 columns four">
    <div class="subfeature-02 columns four">
    <div class="subfeature-03 columns four">
  </div>

  <div class="sub features row">
    <div class="subfeature-04 columns four">
    <div class="subfeature-05 columns four">
  </div>
```

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You haven’t closed your div elements in your HTML, did you mean to do so?

Comment: I was just using it as an example.

Comment: but is what you’ve put the result you actually want to achieve, or should the inner divs all be closed and the first `sub features row` div be closed before the second is open? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: ahh sorry about that, I made the edits!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to organise the data first, then the structure of the Haml will be simple:

```
- @collection_pages.each_slice(3) do |slice|
  .subfeatures.row
    - slice.each do |collection_page|
      %div{class: "subfeature-0#{collection_page.position} columns four"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.subfeatures.row
  - @collection_pages.each_with_index do |collection_page, idx|
    if idx % 3 = 0
      %div{class: "subfeature-row"}
    end
    %div{class: "subfeature-0#{collection_page.position} columns four"}\
```

You can instead use `each_with_index`. For everytime that it equals 0 when it is divided by 3, I create a div  class "sub-feature row"

Comment: Are you talking about the missing `end`?

Comment: `idx` is an index, not a count: on the first iteration, `idx` is equal to `0`, not `1`; on the third iteration, `idx` is equal to `2`, not `3`. `idx % 3 == 0` will not work as expected, use `if (idx+1) % 3 == 0` instead

Comment: That is what I get for editing someone elses post, and not looking at it in depth

Comment: @Mandeep no it should not be `idx % 4 == 0`: Try in your IRB console `(0..12).each{ |n| puts n if n%4 == 0  }`, it is showing every 4th element, not every 3rd.